# logstash cmd not running

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

elasticsearch and kibana both are running  but when i use the following command to ingest csv file into elasticsearch it stops automatically and take a while to respond .

```
bin\logstash -f logstash.config
```

here is my logstash.confg

```
input {
    file {
         path => "C:\Users\Sireesha Chapa\Desktop\logstashData.csv"
         start_position => "beginning"
     }
}

filter {
       csv {
           separator => ","
           columns => ["id","group","sex","disease","age"]
        } 
        mutate { convert => ["id" ,"integer"] } 
        mutate { convert => ["age","integer"] }
}


output {
       elasticsearch {
            hosts => "localhost:9200"
            index => "health"
            document_type => "patient_record"
        }
        stdout{}
}
```

Comment: have you checked the elasticsearch log or logstash logs

Answer (score 0):

Change the name of your logstash config to logstash.conf.

Comment: can you post the logstash error or elasticsearch error